Error with @ManyToOne @OneToMany declarations
 Hi, I am starting with a project with TypeScript, TypeORM and Postgres. I made the entities that seems to be correct but I got some errors I do not understand. The problem found is between a  relationship @ManyToOne - @One ToMany. Here are my declarations and the console error.
// Entity for products table
import  { Category } from './categories/categories.entity';
import { OrderDetails } from 'src/orders/details/orderDetails.entity';
import {
    Column,
    Entity,
    JoinTable,
    ManyToMany,
    ManyToOne,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm';

@Entity({name: 'products`})

export class Product {   
 @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')

    id: string;

    @Column({ length: 50, nullable: false })
    name: string;

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    description: string;

    @Column('decimal', { precision: 10, scale: 2, nullable: false })
    price: number;

    @Column({ nullable: false })
    stock: number;

    @Column({ nullable: true, default: 'default_image_url' })
    imgUrl: string;

    @ManyToOne(() => Category, (category) => category.products)
    @JoinTable()
    category: Category;

    @ManyToMany(() => OrderDetails)
    @JoinTable()
    orderDetails: OrderDetails[];
}

// Pourpose: Entity for categories table
import { Product } from '../products.entity';
import { Column, Entity, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity({ name: 'categories' })
export class Category {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
    id: string;

    @Column({ length: 50, nullable: false })
    name: string;

    @OneToMany(() => Product, (product) => product.category)
    products: Product[];`
}

And here is the error:
src/categories/categories.entity.ts:22:4 - error TS2554: Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.
22   @OneToMany(() => Products)
~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/typeorm/decorator/relations/OneToMany.d.ts:8:102
8 export declare function OneToMany(typeFunctionOrTarget: string | ((type?: any) => ObjectType), inverseSide: string | ((object: T) => any), options?: RelationOptions): PropertyDecorator;
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
An argument for 'inverseSide' was not provided.
src/categories/categories.entity.ts:22:20 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'Products'. Did you mean 'Product'?
22   @OneToMany(() => Products)
~~~~~~~~
src/categories/categories.entity.ts:24:13 - error TS2552: Cannot find name 'Products'. Did you mean 'Product'?
24   products: Products[];
~~~~~~~~
src/categories/categories.entity.ts:24:13 - error TS4031: Public property 'products' of exported class has or is using private name 'Products'.
24   products: Products[];
~~~~~~~~
[10:37:23] Found 4 errors. Watching for file changes.
All declarations are right, and I do not understand what happens. For me seems to be a bug on TypeScript, Pretier. I tried to add a second argument with an empty object {} and with {cascade: true}, but it didn’t work

You can do:


@Column({ nullable: false })
category_id: number;

@ManyToOne(() => Category, (category) => category.id, {
  nullable: false,
  onDelete: "CASCADE",
  onUpdate: "CASCADE",
})
@JoinColumn({
  name: "category_id",
  foreignKeyConstraintName: "category_fk",
})
category: Category;

@ManyToMany(() => OrderDetails)
@JoinTable({
  name: "order_rel",
  joinColumn: { name: "rel_id" },
  inverseJoinColumn: { name: "order_id" },
})
orderDetails: OrderDetails[];



